# Overwriting Hosted Feature Service via REST

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-portal

A quick skills background... Not a full time programmer, proficient enough in Python to get by but VERY new to REST API scripting. So forgive me if there is an easy answer, I am missing something simple or a different approach is warranted.

I am trying to update an existing hosted feature service by using the 'Publish Item' operation using the **overwrite=true** parameter. (API Reference: [ArcGIS REST API - Publish Item](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Publish_Item/02r300000080000000/)).

The following function (minus overwrite param) works perfectly to publish the feature service from an existing geojson item I have already added to Portal.  When I add the overwrite parameter, I get the message that a service with that name already exists. Seems like it checks the service name before recognizing the overwrite parameter.  Service is not delete protected.  Seems simple and straightforward adding of a parameter to the REST call.  Resulting URLs from the original publishing POST call and the update call are the same except for '&overwrite=true' is added to the URL.

What am I missing?

Response Message:
"Publish error for item 'CMT_Test3.geojson'. Service name 'CMT_Test3' already exists"

```
def PublishService(Short, itemID, username, token, itemName, publishParams):
    publishURL =   'http://{}/portal/sharing/rest/content/users/{}/publish'.format(Short, username)
    query_dict = {
        'itemID': itemID,
        'filetype': 'GeoJson',
        'f': 'json',
        'token': token,
        'overwrite': 'true',
        'publishParameters':publishParams}

    query_dict['publishParameters'] = json.dumps(query_dict['publishParameters'], sort_keys=False)
    request = requests.post(publishURL, data=query_dict)
    return request.json()
```

Comment: Have you tried passing `'overwrite': True` instead of `'true'`?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes I have tried every combination of upper or lower case, single quotes and double quotes.  The correct value for JSON Boolean data type is 'true' and I have found examples on the web matching my use of 'overwrite' : 'true' in the dictionary.

See line 216 in the following code:  [link](https://github.com/arcpy/update-hosted-feature-service/blob/master/update.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ESRI this is a bug in the documentation.  Hosted feature services cannot be overwritten.  A documentation bug has been logged to remove the 'overwrite' parameter.

Doc Bug number is:  BUG-000100370